# CocoaPods use locally modified Pods

Tags: cocoapods

I would like to use an existing pod, modify it to fit my needs and finally use it in my Podfile.

So far for the pod I did :

- edit the code
- commit the new code into a new branch
- remove the github origin in the pod's podsspec
- specify the new branch in my podfile with  `:branch`

Now I'm stuck because I cannot get CocoaPods to checkout the modified pod. I tried with :git => 'file:///vendor_custom/test' but it doesn't seems to take into account a relative path. I also copied the .git content and changed it to bare repository type. No luck.

Any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Oh. It was right in the documentation [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#using-the-files-from-a-folder-local-to-the-machine).

```
pod 'YourCustomPod', :path => 'relative/path/...'
```

Comment: Note, if you fork it from it's original location, the name doesn't even need to change. change a few lines in the `podspec` in your repo:master, make your mods (in another branch and merge them into master), and locally in your pod file, add something like … `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'`

Comment: and if you're feeling generous (and it's worthy) send a pull request to the original code of the edited branch (NOTE: don't edit the podspec in your code branch, only in the master, that way it won't be pulled)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you'll miss the future updated from the library which might be bug-fixes or future updates

There is another way in which you can customise it as well as update it in future

Here is an article which i have written explaining the same.

https://medium.com/@mihirpmehta/how-to-modify-cocoapods-library-within-pods-647d2bf7e1cb

[image]