# How to extract pods with cocoapods and then use it locally?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I'm new in iOS development.

I need to know how can I download the pods to put them in a directory, and then how can I link reference local.

For the second part I've seen this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379264/cocoapods-use-locally-modified-pods), and it seems to make sense, but when where can I find the pods?

I mean, first I've downloaded my framework with pod install in a test project, but then when I copy it from Pods dir and try to link the downloaded framework *pod install* crashes with : [!] No podspec found for '<The_Framework>' in '<path_where_I_just_copied>'.

So I need to know WHAT should I copy.
Should I need to download my frameworks from github?
But what directory should I refer?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The answer is github.

Comment: Should I git clone the project and then refer the git cloned path?

Answer (score 2):

Clone the repository from [Github](https://github.com/). Then specify the `path` on your system in the pod file.

```
target 'SomeProject' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'MyCocoapod', :path => '~/Workspaces/SomeLib'
end
```

Then do a `pod install` via terminal as usual.

Comment: but it still isn't enough! When I try to build it needs network connection to resolve something on cocoapods cdn, is there any way to get everything work locally?

Comment: Not sure. Usually, these steps should work. This seems to be a specific issue that you're facing for a particular scenario. Why don't you post the specifics and open another post I'll try to figure out what's required.

Comment: Your pod might have other dependencies, that tried to be resolved via internet.